# Is it possible for an adjective to modify another adjective?

Tags: adjectives, word-usage, colors

While I doubt an adjective *can* modify another one, I'm wondering if it may be possible. Here is the example: "An **immaculate** **black** three-piece suit." Most likely, I'd have to use the adverb *immaculately* to modify *black*, but I could be wrong. What syntactic parses are possible for “an immaculate black three-piece suit”?

(Also, if someone has an answer as to why *bright* in “a bright red car” is grammatical, I’m all ears. *Bright* is an adjective meaning—in that context—vivid and bold [as Oxford defines it], yet it is modifying a second adjective: the color *red*. Is *bright*, or any other word describing color, like *light* in *light red*, the only adjective that can get away with this?)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82154/discussion-on-question-by-the-wordsmith-is-it-possible-for-an-adjective-to-modif).

Comment: Re-posting the link from my comment that was moved to chat: [“Bright” Part of speech](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/315215/bright-part-of-speech) is a relevant older question

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Bright" Part of speech](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/315215/bright-part-of-speech)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the noun Joe wants to describe is the **paper** he just wrote. It has more pages than the average, so one adjective is **long**. We want to modify the way "long" describes the "paper", so we look for some words to make the modification.

Do we want an adjective? No, because "long" is not a noun, though it can be made a noun when you change it to "length". Rather, it is doing something to the word "paper" by describing it, so if we want to modify the description, we need to add an adverb.

For example, if we want to clarify that it is not necessarily among all papers that Joe's is regarded long, but only among this topic, then we might say "Joe wrote a relative**ly** long paper".

Comment: But there's nothing wrong with "Joe wrote a long paper." *Paper* is a noun modified by the adjective *long*.

Comment: Right, because "a" does not refer to "long" but to "paper". Since "long" is *doing* something to the word "paper", the way it's doing that is modified by an adverb.

Comment: Sir, "long" isn't doing anything to the noun "paper." It is simply describing what type of paper *paper* is.

Comment: And "describing" is a verb.

Comment: [These](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/long) are the ways *long* is used as an adverb: (See instance 2.) 1: for or during a long time *long a popular hangout*
2 : at or to a long distance *long-traveled*
3 : for the duration of a specified period *month-long* || *all summer long*
4 : at a point of time far before or after a specified moment or event *was excited long before the big day*
5 : after or beyond a specified or implied time *didn't stay longer than midnight*
6 : for a considerable distance *threw the ball long*
7 : in or into a long position (as on a market)

Comment: *Paper* is not doing anything to warrant the usage of an adverb. If the paper got ripped up, then you *can* use an adverb and say "The paper was ripped up *violently*" or something of the like.

Comment: "The" refers to "paper", which is a noun and described by an adjective, "long". Because "long" is doing the action of describing "paper" in this sentence, it is effectively a verb, and is thus described by an adverb, "relatively".

Comment: In "The paper was ripped up violently", the adverb "violently" is not describing "paper" but the verb "ripped".

Comment: That’s what adverbs do; they modify verbs. *Long* is only a verb when it means to have a desire for something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81972/discussion-between-post169-and-the-wordsmith).

Answer (score 1):

> *an immaculate black three-piece suit*

The absence of punctuation marks this as the '**stacking**' of modifiers. Here there are two layers of modification: "three-piece suit" is first modified by "black" to form the nominal "black three-piece suit", and this in turn is modified by "immaculate" to give the interpretation "three-piece suit that is immaculate by the standards applicable to black ones".

By contrast, if a comma is inserted to give

> *an immaculate, black three-piece suit*

then things are somewhat different. Here, "three-piece suit" is modified by a **coordination** of adjectives, giving the meaning "three-piece suit that is both immaculate and black".

Note: for clarity, I've ignored the compound adjective "three-piece", which is also a modifier.

Comment: The reason I did not punctuate with a comma is because an *and* would be inappropriate here. You do not say “an immaculate AND black three-piece suit.” From *GMEU*: ”When two adjectives modifying the same noun are related in sense, they should be separated by a comma (or else *and*). So we say *a big, sprawling house* and *a poignant, uplifting film*. But when the consecutive adjectives are unrelated, there shouldn’t be a comma—hence *a big white house* and *a poignant foreign film*.” Here is something further from *GMEU*: “If you could use *and* between the adjectives, you’ll need a comma...”

Comment: *Immaculate* and *black* are unrelated in sense and therefore aren’t coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

An adjective doesn't modify another adjective. In the case of the

> immaculate black three-piece suit

"Immaculate" can only modify the noun "suit".

In the case of

> bright red car

There are two ways to parse this. The first is that "bright" modifies the noun "car" directly. The car is both red and bright.

The second (and more usual) way to parse this is to treat "bright red" as one single modifier. The noun is modified by one colour adjective, and that color is "bright red"

Neither of these involve an adjective modifying an adjective.

The reason why we have color terms like "bright red" is because color terms like "red" can take the grammatical role of a noun ("use red with green to make a Christmas theme"), and therefore we can modify them with adjectives. Then we can take the result and use the compound whole as an adjective.