Why are cumulative adjectives not considered to modify nouns equally, as in the case with coordinate adjectives?
I have researched from different websites but cannot find the reasons why cumulative adjectives are not considered to modify the noun equally and why the coordinate adjectives are seen so. So why is this the case? What does "equally" here mean?
Edit:  For example, on Googling "coordinate vs cumulative adjectives", the sixth hit is the website "ProWritingAid", which says:

"Coordinate adjectives modify the same noun equally."
"Cumulative adjectives are also called hierarchical adjectives because they exist in hierarchy.  In other words, they're not all equally important within the sentence."

Following from the above premise, two criteria are alleged to test whether adjectives are coordinate or cumulative:

Coordinate adjectives are separated by a comma and can be separated by "and".  The opposite is true for cumulative adjectives.
Coordinate adjectives can have their order swapped.  The opposite is true for cumulative adjectives.

The examples given are:


Coordinate adjectives:

I got married on a beautiful, sunny day.
I got married on a beautiful and sunny day.
I got married on a sunny, beautiful day.


Cumulative adjectives:

My sister bought a bright green jacket at the store yesterday.
*My sister bought a bright and green jacket at the store yesterday.
*My sister bought a green bright jacket at the store yesterday.



(* marks ungrammatical sentences.)

Google results are cluttered with websites saying the same thing.
But is there empirical and theoretical evidence for the above or is it pseudo-grammar?

Perhaps you could give some examples

What's your source for the claim that they don't modify the noun "equally"?

It seems necessary to consider the reasons of the enormous majority of "beautiful, sunny day"'s, notwithstanding the legions of "sunny, beautiful day"'s : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=beautiful+sunny+day%2Csunny+beautiful+day&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3 , https://www.google.com/search?q=%22sunny%20beautiful%20day%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en .

"bright" modifies "green", not "jacket". "bright green" is a shade of green.

You ask why, but the only answer is "because that's the way it is" or "because English speakers tend to interpret it that way". I don't know what kind of evidence or explanation you want, or why you doubt the truth of something native speakers unconsciously accept. Is there some specific sentence that puzzles you?

What do you mean by "equally"?

Simply put, coordinate adjectives add different descriptions of the head noun they premodify:
Coordinate adjectives:

I got married on a beautiful, sunny day.

=

I got married on a [beautiful] and  [sunny] day.

ie

I got married on a day that was {both} [beautiful] and  [sunny].

..................
With cumulative adjectives, the first in the string actually modifies the second adjective rather than the head noun:

My sister bought a bright green jacket at the store yesterday.

=

My sister bought a [bright green] jacket at the store yesterday.

ie

My sister bought a jacket that is bright green at the store yesterday.

and not, in the first instance,

My sister bought a jacket that is both bright and green at the store yesterday.

'Bright green' is essentially a unary descriptor

('Cumulative adjectives are consecutive. They are also called unit
modifiers.'
Nordquist)

(Though this example is complicated by the fact that the jacket is doubtless also both bright and green.) A better example for the purpose of illustration is

My sister bought an electric blue dress.

............................
There are conflicting usages, however. Another definition of cumulative adjectives has irreversibility (and this brings into consideration the 'Royal Order of Adjectives') as the controlling factor:


Correct: The beautiful Dutch doors opened into the backyard.
Incorrect: The Dutch beautiful doors opened into the backyard. [Grammarist]


Here, it is [Dutch doors] that is the more cohesive unit; 'beautiful' hardly modifies 'Dutch'.
And this can lead to examples where adjectives obviously both equally applying to the head noun are considered cumulative:

a nice little dog
*a little nice dog


It seems to me that that's  not the point, and perhaps, in spite of the trend (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bright-green+jacket%2Cbright+green+jacket&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) it would be better to write "bright-green jacket". Here "bright" must be considered as an adverb rather  (https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/315215/bright-part-of-speech).

Grammars should follow usage, not prescribe. There are few hyphenated examples of electric blue on the internet. One can't dismiss open compounds unilaterally.

@LPH — From the OED: When used with an adjective, bright is sometimes interpreted as an adverb, but historically these are probably better regarded as adjective–adjective combinations.

The NP a beautiful sunny day is most natural when the adjectives are parsed as being 'cumulative' (without a comma or and), don't you agree? Also, in a bright green jacket, bright and green are not cumulative adjectives, they simply form a compound adjective.

@JK2 As I say, the terms are ill-defined (ie [in this case] have conflicting definitions). // Using more precise language, in 'a beautiful sunny day', each premodifier modifies the head noun: either works alone with only loss of information. But there is an idiomatic ... arguably grammatical ... order to the string when pairing them. / In 'a bright green jacket', I'd probably opt for 'compound adjective' (though doesn't CGEL renounce open compounds?) ... a single lexeme. Though 'strong collocation' is arguably an alternative analysis.

I don't think the terms themselves are ill-defined. The specific site cited in the OP uses the terms for the wrong example sentences. And you're following their erroneous classification. // Your explanation "using more precise language" doesn't apply to a beautiful sunny day. It applies only to a beautiful and sunny day or a beautiful, sunny day. //I don't know what you mean CGEL renounces open compounds, but "compound adjective" is exactly what CGEL would classify bright green as.

Having conflicting definitions (definitions conflicting with other reasonably reputable authors) without stipulative definitions being provided at the onset is ill-definition.

"Coordinate adjectives are words used in sequence to modify the same noun, which hold equal weight within the sentence." "Cumulative adjectives are also called hierarchical adjectives because they exist in hierarchy. In other words, they’re not all equally important within the sentence." These definitions are not wrong per se. Their application to specific examples is all messed up. And your answer inadvertently copies the wrong application.

Your question is based on the information in the website you've cited, and the content was written by "a speculative fiction writer". Just because someone has a job as a writer doesn't mean they know grammar cold and/or they can explain grammar better than non-writers.
First, it's unfortunate that the author has beautiful and sunny in the NP a beautiful, sunny day as an example of "coordinate adjectives." You can put a comma or and between beautiful and sunny in the sentence and use them as "coordinate adjectives", but most native speakers wouldn't. This is because it's better to put neither in between and write:

a beautiful sunny day

That is, these work better as "cumulative adjectives". And the structure is:

(1) [NP a [N' beautiful [N' sunny [N' day]]]] [cumulative adjectives]

Here, the adjective beautiful modifies the N' sunny day and the adjective sunny modifies the noun day. So it's better to call these "cumulative adjectives" than "coordinate adjectives", if you must choose between the two.
Like I said, you can theoretically put a comma or and in between and then call these "coordinate adjectives". But they work better as "cumulative adjectives". This is shown in this Ngram.
Second, it's also unfortunate that the author has bight and green in the NP a bright green jacket as an example of "cumulative adjectives." In the most salient interpretation, the NP means "a jacket whose color is bright green". In this meaning, bright green is not "cumulative adjectives" but a compound adjective because bright semantically modifies green. (Cf. Ch. 19, §4.3.1, H&P's CGEL)
So the structure is:

(2) [NP a [N' [Comp Adj bright green] [N' jacket]]]

If, in a less likely scenario, the speaker intended to first describe something as "bright" (meaning "shining strongly") and then identified that something as "green jacket", bright and green could have been "cumulative adjectives." And the structure would be:

(3) [NP a [N' bright [N' green jacket]]]

A better example of "coordinate adjectives" from the site would be:

a gentle, patient man or a gentle and patient man

And the structure is:

(4) [NP a [N' [AdjP gentle and patient] [N' man]]] [coordinate adjectives]

Now, if you compare (1) and (4), you will see the difference between "cumulative adjectives" and "coordinate adjectives". If that makes you understand the claim that "coordinate adjectives" modify the same noun equally but "cumulative adjectives" don't, great. But I wouldn't worry too much about what they mean by "modify the same noun equally".
