# difference between "I'm teasing" and "I'm kidding"

Tags: meaning, phrases, vocabulary

Is there any difference between "teasing" and "kidding"?

Comment: They're synonyms, but I would say that *teasing* is a form of *kidding* taken to a more advanced degree. *Kidding* is probably a bit more playful. Both can be hostile, though.

Comment: Do note that "teasing" is used with other meanings, and those meanings can sort of metaphorically amplify the basic meaning.

Comment: In some zoos, there are boards saying 'don't tease animals'. I am sure, one can't replace the former with the latter.

Answer (score 2):

There are important differences even if both are much founded on joking. The contentions exposed below can be verified on the whole at the entries of the OALD for the verbs in comparison : [kid](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/kid_2), [tease](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/tease_1?q=tease).

1/ "Kidding" does not necessarily involve "making fun" and/or "irritating" whereas "teasing" does.
2/ "Kidding" involves a lie or lies  whereas "teasing" does not necessarily do so and can be based on a distortion of reality such as exaggeration or particular biases that can be found in it or given to it.

However, whether a bout of kidding or of teasing it can always be ended by "[I'm/we are/they are] [just/only] joking.".

Grammatically, there is also an important difference: the verb "to kid" is usually used in the progressive tenses whereas this is not so for "to tease".

Comment: *Kidding* and *lying* are different. The former always is intended to be harmless and to be resolved promptly, whereas the latter always is intended to cause another to leave an interaction carrying false beliefs.

Comment: As @Matt Gutting says, "Hi! What we're really looking for (on this or any other Stack Exchange site) is a **_supported_** answer; one that you can support with authoritative references (in this case a ... dictionary, or some other such document). Edit your question and put in your support; then [more contributors will] be able to vote up your answer."

Answer (score 2):

## Explanation

*Kidding*, strictly an informal or vernacular term, usually describes someone giving a statement, in friendly interaction, that has a literal meaning in contrast to his actual beliefs, as in the sense of an ironic or deceptive joke.

(The term does not indicate being deceitful as someone would find seriously harmful, only at most causing moderate discomfort.)

The other response correctly explains that *to kid* is rarely used in any form other than progressive, as above, though rarely some will say "I kid" for affectation. Also, have never encountered the term in a simple past form. Neither "earlier I *kid* you" or "earlier I *kidded* you" would be acceptable.

---

*Teasing*, equally suitable for formal and informal language, describes statements or actions, also in friendly interaction, that deliberately make another temporarily feel slight discomfort or confusion, in order to promote friendship and bonding.

It might include casual deception, or it might include only true statements, or no statements at all. Thus, acts described as *kidding*  might be  considered a kind teasing, whereas *teasing* carries a more general meaning.

Further, *teasing* is used commonly in a sexual or flirtatious context, as when one deliberately generates a tension between building toward and retreating from an intimate interaction.

## Examples

> **A:** Did you check the lottery draw?
>   **B:** Yes, I won. I'm rich.
>   **A:** Are you kidding me or did you really win?
>   **B:** I'm only kidding, of course.  I didn't win.  I never do.
>   **A:** You know I don't like it when you tease.
>   **B:** How can we have fun without ever teasing each other?

---

*Striptease* describes an art form in which a performer removes clothing in a sexually-suggestive way, such as to cause an onlooker to want her to achieve a greater final state of undress or to proceed at a greater speed than he observes that she actually does.

Comment: The progressive aspect is not limited to the present. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+was+kidding%2Che+is+kidding&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20was%20kidding%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20is%20kidding%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Point accepted.

Comment: Good points in this answer (some already made by LPH). But please read the comment there (originally from Matt Gutting) about the requirements of a good answer on ELU.

Comment: I don't know what the original source is of this remark, but when someone inexperienced with a vernacular asks questions about it, the source of the response material is usually someone's experience. What would you suggest as an authoritative reference to provide this information, and if one is available, what value would you want me to add to the reference information in my response?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Would you give an example illustrating what you might prefer? Obviously, if this very topic is discussed in some reference, then it need not be discussed here, otherwise, the response I gave would seem to me very helpful.

Comment: Look at LPH's answer. ELU expects supporting evidence, quotes from reference works like dictionaries, grammars, academic articles ... correctly attributed and linked. Unsupported answers often come across as (and sometimes are) no more than personal opinion ... which _may_ be right, but .... Either way, they can't be considered to be as reliable as pronouncements from learned lexicographers (for word meanings etc) and grammarians.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth So you just want to links to some dictionary entries?

Comment: Please read the advice at the Help Center. It's useful to read through one or two obviously well-written answers here too. eg [Here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66972/why-is-the-subject-omitted-in-sentences-like-thought-youd-never-ask/66994#66994), [Here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/505015/why-is-dark-an-adverb-in-dark-blue/505039#505039), and  [Here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/137038/give-it-me-write-me/137066#137066)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, Unfortunately, I am still confused about what specific suggestions *you* might offer *me* concerning *this response*. The Help Center indicates that "Links to external resources are encouraged" (though not required), whereas the responses you have linked answer broad issues in the language that have previously been the subject of academic inquiry and debate. None of these references help me understand what *you might concretely suggest in the immediate case*.

Comment: Dictionary support (quote, link & attribution) for (a) the rather precise definition you give for 'kidding', (b) the register it would be found used in, ...